# Is this laser printer ruined?

Tags: printer, toner

I was having a minor streaking problem with my Brother printer, using non-Brother toner (!). Following instructions I removed the cartridge to reposition it when a whole bunch of toner came out, all over the guts of the printer. I began delicately to vacuum it but it's all over the insides as you can see in the photo. Even after removing all 4 cartridges you can see a ton of the magenta.

#### Addded question

Also, I was right to assume that one can handle a toner cartridge without it leaking toner, or was it my stupidity?

#### Can this printer be saved?

[image]

Comment: Its hard to say, but chances are its ruined. The printer will work, but its likely ink got on the toner which will cause for purple smear to be printed with every print. As they say: if you don't use official toners with printers, this is the kind of thing that can happen.

Comment: yeah, lesson learned! But the price difference was so great. Oh, right, "you get what you pay for".

Comment: If you do decide to try and clean it out, please be careful as printer toner can be a carcinogen

Comment: Be careful with vacuums, especially bagless. Toner is very fine and can make its way through filters (and back out the exhaust into the air). And if it doesn't, it has a good chance of permanently clogging your filter.

Comment: Yeah I tried vacuuming for about 20 seconds and it did nothing so I stopped. Will not try again!

Comment: A paper towel (damp or not) may work. It'll stick via static.

Comment: I would try to clean and salvage it before throwing it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be saved... if you can remove all the toner.

That said, **Be Careful** - Printer toner can be a carcinogen.

You maybe able to find a manual for dismantling the printer, to the point at which you can remove each part which has toner on it and clean it separately.

It does infact look like you maybe able to remove each roller itself (or if they are the fuser drum's then they are likely replaceable too).

Another thing to try maybe just to print out a number of blank pages and see what comes out - you might find that most of the toner simply adheres to the first few  sheets and it's fine after that.

Comment: Am I right that a toner cartridge should be able to be handled without spilling toner? That it is defective?

Comment: An inserted cartridge is open on the bottom so that toner can fall out. If you pull the cartridge without first closing/locking it the toner will spill.

Comment: I've not dealt with these model of printers so I don't know. All the ones I ever dealt with (mostly Dells) would have self sealing toner cartridges. However, some did occasionally 'explode'.

Comment: Be careful of parts that you cannot replace.  In our old printer, almost everything along the paper path is replaceable (developers, transfer belts, fusers, drums, etc) but not sure of the new ones  If additional issues persist, diagnose and address those.  DO NOT use compressed air! Aside from health implications, it could displace the toner to areas of the printer it is not in yet and make things worse; I did this for dust and displaced the dust; didn't ruin anything but caused a headache and printing issues even after mitigation for a brief time.

Comment: Carcinogens aren't the worst of it.  This happened with someone's copier and they inhaled some of the toner.  Every time they coughed, they made a duplicate of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't save it. But I gave it to a friend who was more daring than I and it's been working like a champ as the color printer for their whole family for over a year now. Just a cool post-script to the story. So the answer is: "Yes, it could be saved, and it was!"